# Добавление Spinner в андроид приложении

Tags: android

Есть пример добавления Spinner-а в приложение. Объясните как это вообще работает.

```
spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerArrayList);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот элементарный пример добавления `Spinner-a`.

В XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код в Activity:

```
package ru.startandroid.develop.p0561spinner;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   
  String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
   
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         
        // адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // заголовок
        spinner.setPrompt("Title");
        // выделяем элемент 
        spinner.setSelection(2);
        // устанавливаем обработчик нажатия
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        // показываем позиция нажатого элемента
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      }
    });
    }
}
```

Код несложен. Создаем адаптер, используем `simple_spinner_item` в качестве `layout` для отображения `Spinner` на экране. А методом `setDropDownViewResource` указываем какой `layout` использовать для прорисовки пунктов выпадающего списка.

Метод `setPrompt` устанавливает текст заголовка выпадающего списка, а `setSelection` – элемент, который мы хотим выделить. Оба метода, разумеется, необязательны. Я их использовал для демонстрации.

Обработчик выбора элемента из списка присваивается методом `setOnItemSelectedListener`. Будем выводить на экран позицию выбранного элемента.

А если вы еще внимательно почитаете [документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner), то вы сможете подробнее разобраться откуда и что берется. Если же у вас и после этого будут проблемы, то вам скорее всего стоит откатиться назад в вашем обучении и пойти по основам Android.